# Why does equalsIgnoreCase() fail for the letters æ, ø, å when using UTF-8?

Tags: java, localization, special-characters, character-encoding

I am unable to print/compare the letters æøå with the uppercase letters ÆØÅ. My code is running on Mac OS X 10.6.4 in Eclipse STS 2.5 and I have set Eclipse to use UTF-8 instead of MacRoman. It seems that neither equalsIgnoreCase, toUpperCase and toLowerCase work, and I cannot print the letters correctly to the console. Any idea on what I am missing?

Example:

```
String ae1 = "æ";
String ae2 = "Æ";
System.out.println(ae1);
System.out.println(ae2.toLowerCase());
if(ae1.equalsIgnoreCase(ae2))
 System.out.println("match");
else
 System.out.println("no match");
```

Returns:

```
√¶
√ü
no match
```

Comment: What does Apache StringUtils do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's not at all clear which of the following situations you're in:

- Your string literals are being compiled correctly, `equalsIgnoreCase` is failing, and the console is failing
- Your string literals are being compiled incorrectly - and once you've got garbage data, nothing else is going to work

I *strongly* suggest you try using the `\uxxxx` format to make sure you get the right input data. You could analyze your current code by printing out the value of `(int) ae1.charAt(0)` and seeing which Unicode character that is.

Once you've separated things out to work out exactly which stage is failing, you can adjust the code appropriately - whether that's using a `Collator` or some other approach.

Answer (score 3):

Your output clearly says that your source files are UTF-8, but compiler is configured to read sources as Mac OS Roman.

Since you say you configured Eclipse to use UTF-8, perhaps your configuration is somehow wrong or incomplete.

To make sure that it's a problem with source encoding mismatch, you can replace these characters by their Unicode escapes. In this case `equalsIgnoreCase()` works as expected:

```
String ae1 = "\u00e6"; 
String ae2 = "\u00c6";
```

Answer (score 3):

equals() is not meant for comparing natural languages. You should be using Collator: http://java-x.blogspot.com/2006/09/javatextcollator-for-string-comparison.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess my string literals are being compiled incorrectly because the compiler or eclipse is not configured properly, but I have not figured out what it is. Using the `\uxxxx` format did however solved my issues, so I will leave it at that for now.

If i stumble upon a solution I will post it here.

Thanks for your answers!